# How to properly remove a QML File from a QT project

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt-resource

I am trying to remove a QML file from my project.  It is no longer needed.  However, when I delete from the resource then attempt to compile through the IDE, I receive the following error:

:-1: error: No rule to make target '../MAST/fileList.qml', needed by 'debug/qrc_mast.cpp'.  Stop.

What is the proper procedure to remove this file from the project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to clean your project, run qmake and then rebuild the project. If it still gives the error, delete all project build files including make files and then rebuild your project.

Comment: Is this the actual sequence of removing QML files from project? Come on :) There have to be a normal way to do it without clean, rebuild, delete makefile etc.

Comment: @UgaBuga It has nothing to do with QML files. When you remove something from a resource file, qmake does not get it. You should explicitly run qmake (or clean) sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to remove it from the project (`.pro`), too.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the whole build directory (as defined in the project settings) worked for me.